# Onclick for a Image inside an anchor tag is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: activity image]

I have an image tag inside an anchor tag, the image tag has a greyed out star icon  which on click I want to change it to a golden colour star icon, so inside the image tag I have written a `onclick="myFunction('activity');"` which does this bit.

```
<a href="/projects/test-project/activity" class="activity">
<img width="16" height="16" alt="grey star" src="/img/star.png" style="position:relative;left:180px;top:3px;z-index:100" onclick="myFunction('activity');" id="activity">
Activity</a>
```

But the problem is that when I click on the star icon image, the onlick function works but loads up url from the `href="/projects/test-project/activity"` from the anchor tag. How do I click on this image tag and make the page not get loaded?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you provide fiddle for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove onclick function from the html and update the code like this:

**HTML**:

```
<a href="/projects/test-project/activity" class="activity">
    <img width="16" height="16" alt="grey star" src="/img/star.png" 
         style="position:relative;left:180px;top:3px;z-index:100"  id="activity">
    Activity
</a>
```

**JQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#activity').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        myFunction('activity');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

After `onclick`, do `event.stopPropagation()` and `return false();`

```
<a href="/projects/test-project/activity" class="activity">
<img width="16" height="16" alt="grey star" src="/img/star.png" style="position:relative;left:180px;top:3px;z-index:100" onclick="myFunction('activity');event.stopPropagation();return false();" id="activity">
Activity</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery function as below

```js
$(function(){
   $('#activity').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('I am in');
     })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/projects/test-project/activity" class="activity">
    <img width="16" height="16" alt="grey star" src="/img/star.png" style="position:relative;left:180px;top:3px;z-index:100" id="activity">
    Activity</a>
```

Comment: Thanks anto, much appreciate the help

Comment: @Supersonic its my pleasure